# Trouble eliminating a SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that I have been working on all week. I am still new at this, and I appreciate the help I have received thus far.

This Query pulls data from 3 tables, dumps it into a view, then I have a second query to format the data the way the boss wants it. The trouble is, this has to run on SAP B1, which doesn't seem to support views. So I need to write this in a way that does it all in one query.

Here's the first query:

```
SELECT
t2.cardcode as 'BP_Code',
--t0.Recontact as 'Date',
t2.CardName as 'BP_Name',
SubString(T3.Name,1,2) as 'Salesman',
replace(T0.Street,',',' ') as 'Street_Address',
T0.City, 
T0.State, 
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t0.recontact) = 2011 THEN convert(decimal(10,2),t0.U_sold) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Year2011',
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t0.recontact) = 2012 THEN convert(decimal(10,2),t0.U_sold) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Year2012',
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t0.recontact) = 2013 THEN convert(decimal(10,2),t0.U_sold) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Year2013',
convert(decimal(10,2),SUM(t0.U_sold)) as 'Total_Sold'
From 
OCLG t0 -- OCLG is Activities
inner join OCRD t2 -- OCRD is Customer Definitions
on T0.cardcode like t2.cardcode
inner join OCLS t3 -- OCLS is Activity Definitions
on T0.CntctSbjct=T3.Code 
where 
t0.U_sold > 0
and T0.CntctSbjct=T3.Code 
and T0.CardCode=T2.CardCode
and T0.CntctType='3' 
and t2.CardCode = 'a239' --This was added to simplify output
and T0.Recontact >= Convert(date, '2011-01-01' ) and T0.Recontact <= Convert(date,    '2013-12-31' )
group by t2.cardcode, t0.city, t0.state, t0.street, t2.CardName, T3.Name, t0.Recontact
order by t2.CardCode
```

Now, that spits out a table that looks like this:

```
BP_Code    BP_Name     Salesman     Street_Address     City     State     Year2011     Year2012     Year 2013     Total_Sold
A239    Buddy's 01  123 WASHINGTON WASHINGTON     MO    8993.84 0.00    0.00    8993.84
A239    Buddy's 01  123 WASHINGTON WASHINGTON     MO    16474.54    0.00    0.00    16474.54
A239    Buddy's 01  123 WASHINGTON WASHINGTON     MO    0.00    7170.79 0.00    7170.79
A239    Buddy's 01  123 WASHINGTON WASHINGTON     MO    0.00    9207.73 0.00    9207.73
A239    Buddy's 01  123 WASHINGTON WASHINGTON     MO    0.00    0.00    6960.20 6960.20
A239    Buddy's 01  123 WASHINGTON WASHINGTON     MO    0.00    0.00    6787.73 6787.73
```

Now I stick that output in a view called CallReport, and I run this Query on it:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT BP_Code, BP_Name, SalesMan, Street_Address, 
    s = SUM(Total_Sold) OVER (PARTITION BY BP_Code),
    a = SUM(Year2011) OVER (PARTITION BY BP_Code),
    b = SUM(Year2012) OVER (PARTITION BY BP_Code),
    c = SUM(Year2013) OVER (PARTITION BY BP_Code),
    r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BP_Code ORDER BY Date DESC)
  FROM CallReport
)
SELECT BP_Code, BP_Name, Salesman, Street_Address, Year2011 = a, Year2012 = b, Year2013 = c, Total_Sold = s

  FROM x
  WHERE r = 1 and Salesman = 01;
```

Then I get my desired output:

```
 BP_Code    BP_Name Salesman    Street_Address  Year2011    Year2012    Year2013    Total_Sold
 A239   Buddy's 01  123 WASHINGTON 25468.38 16378.52    13747.93    106804.83
```

See what the problem is? I have hundreds of BP_Codes, I am just narrowing A239 for this example. I need each BP_code to only be on one line, with sum sales data for each year, and grand total. I know there's a way to do this easier, but I am still new to the game. Any ideas? This is on MSSQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood this correctly u are trying to modify the view to get the desired output,below is the code for it

```
SELECT
t2.cardcode as 'BP_Code',
--t0.Recontact as 'Date',
t2.CardName as 'BP_Name',
SubString(T3.Name,1,2) as 'Salesman',
replace(T0.Street,',',' ') as 'Street_Address',
T0.City, 
T0.State, 
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t0.recontact) = 2011 THEN convert(decimal(10,2),t0.U_sold) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Year2011',
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t0.recontact) = 2012 THEN convert(decimal(10,2),t0.U_sold) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Year2012',
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t0.recontact) = 2013 THEN convert(decimal(10,2),t0.U_sold) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Year2013',
convert(decimal(10,2),SUM(t0.U_sold)) as 'Total_Sold'
From 
OCLG t0 -- OCLG is Activities
inner join OCRD t2 -- OCRD is Customer Definitions
on T0.cardcode like t2.cardcode
inner join OCLS t3 -- OCLS is Activity Definitions
on T0.CntctSbjct=T3.Code 
where 
t0.U_sold > 0
and T0.CntctSbjct=T3.Code 
and T0.CardCode=T2.CardCode
and T0.CntctType='3' 
and t2.CardCode = 'a239' --This was added to simplify output
and T0.Recontact >= Convert(date, '2011-01-01' ) and T0.Recontact <= Convert(date,    '2013-12-31' )
group by t2.cardcode, t0.city, t0.state, replace(T0.Street,',',' '), t2.CardName, SubString(T3.Name,1,2)
order by t2.CardCode
```

all I did was to correct your groupby clause, you were getting multiple records due to  t0.Recontact in group by.

If you have multiple values in t0.city, t0.state, replace(T0.Street,',',' '), t2.CardName, SubString(T3.Name,1,2) columns for a BP_Code and u want to pick one of the values of these columns then use below code

```
SELECT
t2.cardcode as 'BP_Code',
--t0.Recontact as 'Date',
max(t2.CardName) as 'BP_Name',
max(SubString(T3.Name,1,2)) as 'Salesman',
max(replace(T0.Street,',',' ')) as 'Street_Address',
max(T0.City) City, 
max(T0.State) State, 
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t0.recontact) = 2011 THEN convert(decimal(10,2),t0.U_sold) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Year2011',
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t0.recontact) = 2012 THEN convert(decimal(10,2),t0.U_sold) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Year2012',
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t0.recontact) = 2013 THEN convert(decimal(10,2),t0.U_sold) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Year2013',
convert(decimal(10,2),SUM(t0.U_sold)) as 'Total_Sold'
From 
OCLG t0 -- OCLG is Activities
inner join OCRD t2 -- OCRD is Customer Definitions
on T0.cardcode like t2.cardcode
inner join OCLS t3 -- OCLS is Activity Definitions
on T0.CntctSbjct=T3.Code 
where 
t0.U_sold > 0
and T0.CntctSbjct=T3.Code 
and T0.CardCode=T2.CardCode
and T0.CntctType='3' 
and t2.CardCode = 'a239' --This was added to simplify output
and T0.Recontact >= Convert(date, '2011-01-01' ) and T0.Recontact <= Convert(date,    '2013-12-31' )
group by t2.cardcode
order by t2.CardCode
```

Comment: You are my hero! The first one almost worked (I can't believe I was so close...), except when there was a difference in the address. The second one worked perfectly!